# how to disable the key using jquery when the page is been loaded?

Tags: jquery

I have downloaded a jquery numeric keypad plugin from the link http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html . Now i want to disable a key when the page is been loaded. 
I tired in all ways but i din get any solution . The key should be disabled once the page is been loaded .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "I tired in all ways but i din get any solution"   Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

for disabling key `1`

use this `:contains(keypad-key text)` for number 1 `:contains(1)`

```
$('#defaultKeypad').focus(function () {
    $('.keypad-key').filter(':contains(1)').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: Hi I want to add a color to the key when the key has been disabled once after clicking... can you help me .

Comment: Try `$('.keypad-key').filter(':contains(1)').css('background-color','grey')`

Comment: Thanks Gupta... I tried in this way it worked for me  $('.keypad-key').filter(':contains(+)').attr('disabled', true).css('background-color', 'rgba(73, 105, 100, 0.28)');;

Comment: Gupta ... I want to add a new language into my application using jquery .. Can you tell me the ways to add and what all do be done. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Sujeeth make a new question that will more better .